# Configuring IPv6 on Debian - Global temporary address

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ipv6

My Mac generates a daily temporary IPv6 for outbound connection usage.

Is there something similar that's available on Debian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a static address in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2001:xxx:7927::61
netmask 64
gateway 2001:xxx:7927::1
```

You can also add additional interfaces (like eth0:0, eth0:1) in the same way.

---

To get a 'random' IPv6 address you can use the IPv6 Privacy Extension. You can enable it by setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conff/ethX/use_tempaddr` to 2. This is described in [ip-sysctl.txt](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?id=HEAD):

```
echo "2">/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conff/eth0/use_tempaddr
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mtak. I'll try the use_tempaddr, but I'm not sure the first part is what I'm looking for. Because my concern is if/when the delegated prefix from Comcast changes, the manual address in /etc/network/interfaces will no longer be reachable