# Configuring a static IPv6 address that inherits delegated prefix

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ipv6

My ISP (comcast) delegates a prefix, my router is passing along the prefix delegation (pd) onto the LAN. My Debian machine is getting the prefix and appending using EUI-64 address. That's nice but not very memorable. I prefer to have an additional "vanity" address within the PD prefix.

Some specificity:

- The PD is (e.g., 2601:8:abcd:abcd/64)
- My Linux box autoconfigures eui-64: 2601:8:abcd:abcd:DEAD:BEff:feEF:CAFE (for MAC DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE)

What I'd like is to manually create an interface: 2601:8:abcd:abcd::2 as a static global address, but if the Comcast prefix delegation changes, have the interface adopt the new delegated prefix and use the static suffix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring IPv6 on Debian - Global manual permanent addresses with delegated prefix](http://superuser.com/questions/806242/configuring-ipv6-on-debian-global-manual-permanent-addresses-with-delegated-pr)

Comment: Edited my other question to be just about temporary address. I shouldn't have asked a 2 part question, it makes it difficult to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
ip token set ::dead:beef/64 dev eth0
```

From what I understand, you run that before running whatever you usually run to get an IP6 address, and `0:0:dead:beef` will be used instead of the normal EUI-64.

Strangely, this doesn't seem to add a corresponding link-local address, instead adding the normal EUI-64 with the `fe80::/64` prefix. You can fix this manually with:

```
ip addr flush scope link dev eth0
ip addr add fe80::dead:beef/64 dev eth0
```

Replace the suffix, prefix size, and interface (`::dead:beef`, `/64`, `eth0`) as appropriate.

Comment: That definitely looks promising. Looks like I have to upgrade my kernel though to take advantage of it. I'll update when I've had a chance to upgrade.

Comment: You must be running an *old* kernel. In case you (or anyone else) is interested, [*token* is a feature added to *iproute2* in 2013](https://github.com/IxLabs/iproute2/commit/191b60bd73d50a9197302417a2fc119d71d11005).

Comment: Yeah. I saw that as well but when I checked my kernel build date it was 2012. I had downloaded the newer iproute2 package that supported token and it complained about lack of support.

Comment: Works great, noticed it doesn't create the MAC-based ff:fe address, but that's no big loss.

Comment: Do you know of a way to add multiple tokens / configure multiple such "static dynamic" addresses?

Answer (score 4):

As in the meantime Network Manager is used by default in almost all GNU/Linux distributions (according to http://news.softpedia.com/news/networkmanager-1-4-adds-support-for-setting-ipv6-tokenized-interface-identifiers-507601.shtml) I thought this other discussion at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403541/259695 may be helpful. The token can be set by

```
nmcli connection modify eth0 ipv6.method "auto" # if not already
nmcli connection modify eth0 ipv6.addr-gen-mode "eui64" # use interface token
nmcli connection modify eth0 ipv6.token "::dead:beef" # or "::2" - as you like
```

which will write `IPV6_TOKEN=::dead:beef` to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 to survive a reboot. To immediate apply this restart the interface by

```
nmcli connection up id eth0  # restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to announcing the network prefix, you would need to use stateful DHCPv6 service.

Similar to DHCPv4, DHCPv6 server in stateful mode assigns hosts the addresses from the range you desire - and it can be a very small range, for instance 2601:8:abcd:abcd::10-2601:8:abcd:abcd::99. I've been using [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) in my routers.

Typically, in addition to address assigned by DHCPv6, hosts will still autonomously generate unicast IPv6 address - each interface will have two (or even more) of them. You can switch that behavior off by modifying configuration of the router - disabling the autonomous address configuration flag will do the trick. But will also render majority Android devices unable to get IPv6 address; Android (at least with KitKat 4.4.4) still does not properly support DHCPv6...

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the reply Grogi. However, the host in question *is* my DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe this question hasn't been answered yet!

Great [answer by Jürgen](https://superuser.com/a/1266966/167207) but not applicable for servers which use networkd to render the network rather than the NetworkManager.

For servers in need of a self-adjusting, semi static IPv6 we have to add the line

```
ipv6-address-token: "::ace:face"
```

to the interface description in netplan yaml. e.g.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      ipv6-address-token: "::ace:face"
      addresses:
        - <ipv4 static address>
      nameservers: ...
```

However, if IP forwarding is enabled, following line must be added to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to override disabling of the `accept_ra` default by networkd. The logic (if we are a router, we shouldn't accept ra from other routers) makes sense but doesn't apply in some cases.

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=2
```

The line in sysctl conf forces acceptance of router anouncement (ra) despite the ip forwarding setting. This is essential as the the ra informs us of the delegated prefix.

The line IPv6 address token template in netplan is for generating the IPv6 address that uses the router provided prefix and our specified address to generate the address. So, we end up with an address of the form of

```
<delegated prefix>::ace:face/<bit length of netmask>
```

Still, not fully static but predictable, and I don't have to reconfigure every server when the prefix changes.